# How to add subitems to navigation drawer in android like expandable list

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

I'm working on a demo of **DrawerLayout** with fragments in android,I've implemented it but I want to add **subitems** to items when it is clicked it should populate the subitems just like an expandable listView. I have found some thread with expandable ListView,But I don't want it,Please suggest me how can I do it?

**menu.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">



    <item android:title="Customer">
        <menu
            >
            <item
                android:id="@+id/nav_cust_mgmt"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_group"
                android:title="Customer Management" >

            </item>


            <item
                android:id="@+id/nav_cust_opn"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_user"
                android:title="Customer Operation" />
            <item
                android:id="@+id/nav_cust_tkt"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_page"
                android:title="Customer Tickets" />
        </menu>
    </item>

    <item android:title="LCO">
        <menu>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/nav_dashboard"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_home"
                android:title="Dashboard" />
            <item
                android:id="@+id/nav_stm"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_stmnt"
                android:title="Statement of Account" />
            <item
                android:id="@+id/nav_staf_mgmnt"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_grup"
                android:title="Staff Management" />
            <item
                android:id="@+id/nav_my_tkts"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_page"
                android:title="My Tickets" />
            <item
                android:id="@+id/nav_logout"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_logout"
                android:title="Logout" />
        </menu>
    </item>

</menu>
```

I want to add subcategories to this.Please help me.

Answer (score -1):

You can create groups in menu file like this

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/nav_menuItem9"
    android:title="@string/str_drawer_group1">
        <menu android:checkableBehavior="all">

            <group android:checkableBehavior="single">
                <item
                    android:id="@+id/nav_cust_mgmt"
                    android:icon="@drawable/ic_group"
                    android:title="Customer Management" >

                </item>
                    ...
            </group>
        </menu>
</item>
```

OR you can put expandable list view in drawer part and then handle everything manually. for more about this check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23195740/how-to-implement-expandable-android-navigation-drawer-with-subitems)

Comment: Can you add ss of result ?

Comment: i dint have enuf reputaion points to upload image of ecreemshot.

Comment: Upload on imugr or some other site and then paste link here...  Or update your code in question so I can check what you have done.